# GridSearchCV: How to specify test set?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, text-classification

I have a question regarding `GridSearchCV`:

by using this:

```
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=-1, cv=6, scoring="f1")
```

I specify that k-fold cross-validation should be used with 6 folds right?

So that means that my corpus is split into training set and tet set 6 times.

Doesn't that mean that for the `GridSearchCV` I need to use my entire corpus, like so:

```
gs_clf = gs_clf.fit(corpus.data, corpus.target)
```

And if so, how would I then get my trainig set from there used for the predict method?

```
predictions = gs_clf.predict(??)
```

I have seen code where the corpus is split into test set and training set using `train_test_split` and then `X_train` and `Y_train` are passed to `gs_clf.fit`.

But that doesn't make sense to me: If I split it the corpus beforehand, why use cross validation again in the `GridSearchCV`?

Thanks for some clarification!!

Comment: This is a great question; thanks for putting it out there!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. `GridSearchCV` is not designed for measuring the performance of your model but to optimize the hyper-parameter of classifier while training. And when you write `gs_clf.fit` you are actually trying different models on your entire data (but different folds) in the pursuit of the best hyper-parameter. For example, if you have n different `c`'s and m different `gamma`'s for an SVM model, then you have n X m models and you are searching (grid-search) through them to see which one works best on your data.
2. When you found the best model using `gs_clf.best_params_`, then you can use your test data to get the actual performance (e.g., accuracy, precision, ...) of your model.
3. Of course, only then it is time for testing the model. Your test data must not have any overlap with the data you trained your model against. For instance, you should have something like `corpus.train` and `corpus.test`, and you should reserve `corpus.test` only for the last round when you are done with training and you only want to test the final model.

As we all know, any use of test data in the process of training the model (where training data should be used) or tuning the hyper-parameters (where the validation data should be used) is considered cheating and results in unrealistic performance.

Answer (score -1):

Cross-validation and test percentile are different ways to measure the algorithm accuracy. Cross-validation does what you have said. Then, you must give all the data to the classifier. Splitting the data when using cross-validation makes simply no sense.

If you want to measure precision or recall using `GridSearchCV`, you must create a `scorer` and assign it to the scoring parameter of `GridSearchCV`, like in this example:

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import fbeta_score, make_scorer
>>> ftwo_scorer = make_scorer(fbeta_score, beta=2)
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
>>> from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
>>> grid = GridSearchCV(LinearSVC(), param_grid={'C': [1, 10]}, scoring=ftwo_scorer)
```

Comment: But isnt that what's happening here? https://civisanalytics.com/blog/data-science/2016/01/06/workflows-python-using-pipeline-gridsearchcv-for-compact-code/. And If I give all the data to the classifier, what do I use for the predict function?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be that, and is used when they create a report to see accuracy by precision and recall. By the way, if they do this measurement in this way, dont make sense to use cross validation. Is some kind of educational mixing, but with no sense in real world. You must use the predict function when you have a new input without label and you want to predict the label for this input, im saying, when you want to make predictions.

Comment: Okay, so use the entire corpus and use predict for new data. And how would I get precision, accuracy and recall from the GridSearchCV? I cant tell how to do this from the sklearn documentation.

Comment: You must create an scorer and assign it to the scoring parameter of gridsearchcv, like in this example:`>>> from sklearn.metrics import fbeta_score, make_scorer
>>> ftwo_scorer = make_scorer(fbeta_score, beta=2)
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
>>> from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
>>> grid = GridSearchCV(LinearSVC(), param_grid={'C': [1, 10]}, scoring=ftwo_scorer)`

Comment: I am using the f1 parameter, like described here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter. But thats just to define the scoring, right? How do I get the actual values for accuracy, recall and precison?

Comment: Basically I would like a classification_report, but using the GridSearchCV and not the predictions afterwards.